# Java read file with strings from different languages

Tags: java, encoding, csv

I made a program that reads different text files and combines this into a .csv file. Its a .csv file with translations into English, dutch, french, italian, portuguese and spanish.

Now here is my problem:

In the end i get a nice filled .csv file with all the translations together. I read the files with UTF-8 and all the languages get shown right except for the french one. Some chars are shows as Questionmarks like these: "Mis ? jour" and it should be "Mis à jour".

Here is the method that reads the different files with the different languages and makes objects from them so i can sort them en put them in the right spot in the .csv file

The files are filled like this:

To Airport;A l’aéroport

Today;Aujourd’hui

```
public static Language getTranslations(String inputFileName) {
    Language language = new Language();

     FileInputStream fstream;
    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(inputFileName), "UTF-8"));
        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            String[] values = strLine.split(";");
            if(values.length == 2) {
                language.putTranslationItem(values[0], values[1]);
            }
    }

      //Close the input stream
    in.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return language;
}
```

I hope anybody can help out!

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked whether the files containing the french texts are actually *read* correctly to begin with? Maybe the input from those files is already mangled (wrong encoding or something).

Comment: Yes that text is correct. It goes wrong when reading it on Eclipse

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong here. Is it the above code that's reading string with question marks, or is it the CSV file that contains question marks, or both? Are you sure the file is UTF-8 encoded? My guess is that it's not. (Side note: your code should really be fixed. Don't ignore exceptions, don't open useless streams, and always close them in finally blocks)

Comment: I would suspect that at one step, a file is in a different encoding than you think it is. It strikes me as perculiar that your csv file would be UTF8, when editing with MS-Excel, its most likely not UTF8.

Comment: Thanks for the side note! I only run this code ones to create the csv file. The reason i did this was because i could not handle copy pasting thousands of records that are in different orders. 

When i debug the strings its already with questionmarks, maybe you are right about the file not beeing utf-8 encoded. I will try to find a way to check that.

Comment: I found out that the file is utf-16. Opened it in firefox and checked the fileinfo

Comment: @fergers, did you get the solution of this problem? I am facing the same problem. CSV modifies the data in a different language. for i.e.CignexIns - 新學院 becomes CignexIns - ?겼???- CA. Although it opens up correctly if I open it in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about this , but you can try to convert the values[0] and values[1] strings into bytearray

```
byte[] value_0_utfString = values[0].getBytes("UTF-8") ;
byte[] value_1_utfString = values[1].getBytes("UTF-8") ;
```

and then convert it back into a string

```
str_0 = new String(value_0_utfString ,"UTF-8") ;
str_1 = new String(value_1_utfString ,"UTF-8") ;
```

Not sure if this is the right / optimized way , but since a single line comprises of both english and french , I thought splitting and encoding might help , I haven't tried this myself

Answer (score 0):

Resave the text file by clicking "save as" in any text editor(eg: memopad) and change the encoding type to ANSI instead of UTF-8.